# Randomizing again after unbalanced covariates

Tags: experiment-design, inference, random-allocation

Assume you want to perform an experiment in order to assess the influence of a treatment on the outcome. 
You randomly allocate treatments to subjects, e.g. by using a random number generator (in R: 'crPar' of the 'randomizeR' package). You then realize that (a) the number of participants between both experimental groups is highly different, or (b) both groups are highly unbalanced based on covariates of the participants.

As far as I know, this could have been avoided by using a random allocation procedure such as Representing Permuted Block Randomization (in R: 'pbrPar' of the 'randomizeR' package).

My question: What 'happens' when just randomizing again? What does 'hitting randomize' again, or 'changing the seed' after observing what happened, not being satisfied with the outcome, and then 'correcting' it like this, cause?

Is there some theoretical or argumentative way to explain what is wrong with this? My intuition tells me that it is almost certainly fraud, but I would like to understand the argument and statistics behind it better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It probably helps to answer this to consider why we allocate using a random process. We do this to avoid as far as possible selection bias where people have been allocated to the treatment which the researcher wants them to have for some ulterior motive.

There is in general therefore nothing in principle to stop you changing your mind and altering your randomisation process. One example which sometimes comes up is where a trial started randomising 1:1 but then found the treatment process could not cope with so many people at once and changed to 1:2. Of course this must be reported and justified.

To take your two examples I would suggest that obtaining an extreme imbalance in numbers is just a mistake which should have been avoided by choosing a better randomisation process and you can re-do it. I am less happy about re-randomising to achieve a balance of covariates because I do not think you should know the covariates yet split by allocation and so there is a strong risk here that you can be accused of inducing selection bias, probably inadvertently.